# Implementing SQL in a Bukkit/Spigot plugin

Tags: mysql, sql, minecraft, bukkit

First of all, I'm new to these forums, so I'm sorry if (or when) I make a tiny mistake somewhere.

After having learned HTML and CSS a while ago, I recently started learning Java.
I'm a developer at a Minecraft server network, and one of the plugins I made is one that enables /color [color code or color name].

Now, I've set up a MySQL database in which I created a table with UUID and Color as variables.
I've been struggling to let the plugin connect to the database and store/retrieve the color of the player's name he chose, because it needs to work across multiple servers.

I'd like the plugin to be optimised, so it only connects if needed and disconnects with the SQL database so it doesn't give too much lag.
This is the code I have till now:

```
package nl.live.partyblaze.pbcolor;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class PBColor extends JavaPlugin
{
    @Override
    public void onEnable()
    {
        getLogger().info("[PBColor] onEnable has been invoked!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable()
    {
        getLogger().info("[PBColor] onDisable has been invoked!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
    {
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("color"))
        {
            if (args.length == 1)
            {
                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§aYour name has been set to green!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("green"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§aYour name has been set to green!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.AQUA + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§bYour name has been set to aqua!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("aqua"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.AQUA + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§bYour name has been set to aqua!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§cYour name has been set to red!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("red"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§cYour name has been set to red!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§dYour name has been set to light purple!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("lightpurple"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§dYour name has been set to light purple!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.YELLOW + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§eYour name has been set to yellow!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("yellow"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.YELLOW + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§eYour name has been set to yellow!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.WHITE + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§fYour name has been set to white!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("white"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.WHITE + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§fYour name has been set to white!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§1Your name has been set to dark blue!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("darkblue"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§1Your name has been set to dark blue!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§2Your name has been set to dark green!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("darkgreen"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§2Your name has been set to dark green!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("3"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§3Your name has been set to dark aqua!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("darkaqua"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§3Your name has been set to dark aqua!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_RED + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§4Your name has been set to dark red!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("darkred"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_RED + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§4Your name has been set to dark red!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("5"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§5Your name has been set to dark purple!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("darkpurple"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§5Your name has been set to dark purple!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("6"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GOLD + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§6Your name has been set to gold!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("gold"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GOLD + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§6Your name has been set to gold!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("7"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GRAY + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§7Your name has been set to gray!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("gray"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GRAY + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§7Your name has been set to gray!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("8"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§8Your name has been set to dark gray!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("darkgray"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§8Your name has been set to dark gray!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("9"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.BLUE + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§9Your name has been set to blue!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("blue"))
                {
                    String displ = sender.getName();
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    p.setDisplayName(ChatColor.BLUE + displ);
                    sender.sendMessage("§9Your name has been set to blue!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is exactly your question? You seem to be talking about reviewing your code, what is offtopic here, but on topic on CodeReview. But you also talk about implementing mysql in your plugin, what would be on-topic here, but I don't see any database related code in what you posted, unless you were asking for a tutorial about mysql, what is off-topic. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34856113/edit) your question to clairify.

Comment: @Ferrybig from what I gather this code does not yet work as intended. If that is the case, the question is unfortunately **off-topic** at Code Review. For reference I recommend you (and PartyBlaze) to read through the [Code Review Help Center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and through the [Guide To Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I'm sorry. As I said, I am new to these forums. I meant to ask how I integrated MySQL in the plugin as how I explained. @Ferrybig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my plugin, I use this Class, which I named `MySQL`:

```java
package me.Nightfighter001.Minepedia-System.Methoden;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.ConsoleCommandSender;

public class MySQL {

    public static String host = "minepedia.eu";
    public static String port = "3306";
    public static String database = "GlobalData";
    public static String username = "******";
    public static String password = "*****";
    public static Connection con;

    static ConsoleCommandSender console = Bukkit.getConsoleSender();

    // connect
    public static void connect() {
        if (!isConnected()) {
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, username, password);
                console.sendMessage("\247c[\2476Minepedia-System\247c] \247bMySQL-Verbindung wurde aufgebaut!");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // disconnect
    public static void disconnect() {
        if (isConnected()) {
            try {
                con.close();
                console.sendMessage("\247c[\2476Minepedia-System\247c]\247bMySQL-Verbindung wurde geschlossen!");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // isConnected
    public static boolean isConnected() {
        return (con == null ? false : true);
    }

    // getConnection
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }
}
```

In `onEnable()` you should call `MySQL.connect();` and then in `onDisable()` call `MySQL.disconnect();`. This will properly connect and disconnect the MySQL instance.

This code is written with the assumption you indent to run this on Bukkit/Spigot, to run it in BungeeCord instead, you should replace the `CommandSender` with the BungeeCord equivalent.

Some examples for `PreparedStatements`:

Creating a `Table`:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Players (Name VARCHAR(100),UUID VARCHAR(100),Coins INT(100),PRIMARY KEY (Name))");
ps.executeUpdate();
```

`PRIMARY KEY` means, that `Name` can not be duplicated.
`VARCHAR` is nearly the same as a `String`.

Empty a `Table`:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("TRUNCATE Players");
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Insert something to a `Table`:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT IGNORE INTO Players (Name,UUID,Coins) VALUES (?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1, Player.getName());
ps.setString(2, Player.getUniqueId());
ps.setInt(3, 10);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

With `setString()` / `setInt()`, I replace the Questionmark.

Delete something from `Table`:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Players WHERE Name = ?");
ps.setString(1, Player.getName());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Read from `Table`:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT Coins FROM Players WHERE Name = ?");
ps.setString(1, Player.getName());
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
int coins = 0;
if (rs.next() == true) {
    coins = rs.getInt("Coins");
}
```

If you want to get everything from `Players` where the `Name` equals `Player.getName()`, you can use `*` in place of `Coins`.

I hope this helps. And sorry for my bad English again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more thing, how do I let the plugin store and retrieve database variables, and let it disconnect after that (for less lag)? 
And where did you get the MySQL API you imported at lines 7 and 8? @Nightfighter001

Comment: I have worked on my answer with some examples. I hope that they can help you! And I do not think that a MySQL-Connection causes lags. There might be more lags, when you disconnect and connect again very often. @PartyBlaze

Comment: Thank you so much! The only thing I need now is the `import net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord` and `import net.md_5.bungee.api.CommandSender`.

Comment: I programmed the Class `MySQL` again, and now for Bukkit/Spigot. I hope it works

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I do need it for BungeeCord, but I couldn't find the files to import. Sorry! @Nightfighter001

Comment: Of course import `net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord` and `import net.md_5.bungee.api.CommandSender` exist! Just try it again or check your BungeeCord Version. Here the line for the `CommandSender` again: `static CommandSender console = BungeeCord.getInstance().getConsole();`